# Importing Markdown2 in template tag

Tags: python, django, import, django-templates, importerror

I needed Markdown syntax for my blog. I decided to use [python-markdown2 library](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2). I follow TDD process so I created tests in which I imported Markdown library and it worked. Then all I needed was to convert some of the output so that all tests pass. I think that it's more like a presentation logic, so I created template tag in which I want to import library and... that as far as I got. Problem is that I can't import that library! I debugged for hours and I still can't find a reason why.

Few facts:

1. It's imported in *tests.py* before (so it does exist),
2. Without using external library, template tag works fine;

The precise error message:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /article/1/foo-bar/
'cheese' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading blog.templatetags.cheese: cannot import name markdown
```

Here's *templatetags/cheese.py*:

```
from django import template
import markdown2

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def eggs(value):
    return value
```

Here's template:

```
{% load cheese %}
```

P.S. If needed, [full error](https://gist.github.com/3600252) and [all code](https://github.com/daGrevis/daGrevis.lv/tree/task_%237).

Comment: what happens if you just try to `import cheese` from an interactive shell?

Comment: @Claudiu https://gist.github.com/3600016

Comment: When you paste the traceback, please click "switch to cut and paste mode" first, it makes things much easier to read.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ohh, didn't new about it. Fixed!

Comment: @daGrevis: what's `markdown2.py`? It's not in the git repo

Comment: @Claudiu It isn't because it's manually installed using pip and binary files are hidden using _.gitignore_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback shows something that isn't present in your github repo: there is a file in the templatetags directory called `markdown2.py`, which is imported when the `cheese` file does `import markdown2`. Remove this file, and it should find the right one.

Comment: Yes, there was some trash file in _templatetags_ dir only locally. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

From console, having your Virtualenv activated in project's directory, try:

```
pip install markdown2
```

That helped me, having the same issue. I have checked, using

```
pip freeze
```

that markdown2 were not actually installed, even thought it was shown in PyCharm.